# Reading in JSON object from Working Directory using javascript (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read a JSON object in from json.js into my main.js. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the values from the external json.js file into the main.js without using jQuery. I know it's possible, but can't figure out the solution (I've been searching for hours).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can use Ajax... there is no need to use jQuery for that

Comment: no with plain old [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on that? All I can seem to find is URL requests for JSON objects using Ajax.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why can't you include json.js and access the object directly?

Comment: When you say working directory are you using a web server or loading straight from the file system?

Comment: As in it's in the same folder as main.js. Not on a web server.

Comment: Rick Hanlon I would like it if it is in a separate file so that I can learn how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plain old [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
function loadJson() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var json = JSON.parse(text);
            console.log(json)
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "json.js?_dc" + Math.random(), false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

loadJson();
```

Comment: What is `.onreadystatechange`? What is that function even doing, along with `"json.js?_dc" + Math.random()`?

Comment: @JonBecher probably you should read about [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)

Comment: After reading up on what you were doing with this I figured out how to use it in my application. Thank you Arun.